# Unable to copy the shared library's soft links with their original size in linux

Tags: linux, shared-libraries, redhat, dynamic-linking, dynamic-library

I have created a shared object of 1.2 M and created 4 soft links for that SO.
Size of all the links is 20B and the size of the main so is 1.2M

```
20         May 23 10:56 libAbc.so -> libAbc.so.2.0.11.0
20         May 23 10:56 libAbc.so.1 -> libAbc.so.2.0.11.0
20         May 23 10:56 libAbc.so.1.0 -> libAbc.so.2.0.11.0
1.2M        May 23 10:56 libAbc.so.2.0.11.0
```

While i tried  to copy all these files to another folder using cp , the size of the links is equal to the main file.

```
1.2M May 24 08:07 libABC.so
1.2M May 24 08:07 libABC.so.1
1.2M May 24 08:07 libABC.so.1.0
1.2M May 24 08:07 libABC.so.2.0.11.0
```

I have also used

```
cp -s libAgent.so* src/
```

which is also failing with an error

```
cp: `src/libAgent.so': can make relative symbolic links only in current directory
```

Why is it failing to copy the softlinks with their original size(20B)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copying a soft link usually copies the file the soft link refers to and does not replicate the soft link.

If you wish to use `cp` to copy soft links as new soft links, specify the *-a* option to `cp`.

```
cp -a libAbc.so* /path/to/another/folder
```

The *info* page for `cp` says:

```
`-a'
`--archive'
     Preserve as much as possible of the structure and attributes of the
     original files in the copy (but do not attempt to preserve internal
     directory structure; i.e., `ls -U' may list the entries in a copied
     directory in a different order).  Equivalent to `-dpR'.
```

The key is to select the "archive" option of the command used to copy the link.  `rsync` is an effective alternative as Maxim Egorushkin points out, and `rsync` has the capability of copying extended attributes and ACLs if the command includes the appropriate command-line arguments.

```
rsync -aAX libAbc.so* /path/to/another/folder
```

The `rsync` man page says:

```
-a, --archive               archive mode; equals -rlptgoD (no -H,-A,-X)
    --no-OPTION             turn off an implied OPTION (e.g. --no-D)
-A, --acls                  preserve ACLs (implies -p)
-X, --xattrs                preserve extended attributes
```

In the OP's use case, the *-A* and *-X* are not needed.

A caveat is that if the soft link is a relative link, copying it to a new  location may make the link inoperative because it does not point to an absolute path.

For example:

```
$ ls -al /usr/lib/rpmpopt
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 19 2012-05-02 12:40 /usr/lib/rpmpopt -> rpm/rpmpopt-4.4.2.3
```

`cp -a /usr/lib/rpmpopt ${HOME}/tmp` and `rsync -av /usr/lib/rpmpopt ${HOME}/tmp` on my machine both create a broken link `rpmpopt -> rpm/rpmpopt-4.4.2.3` because my local copy has no *rpm* sub-folder.  One needs to consider this fact when deciding what to copy.

This link is broken because *${HOME}/tmp/rpm* is not present:

```
$ ls -nl ${HOME}/tmp/rpmpopt
lrwxrwxrwx 1 505 700 19 2016-05-24 10:04 /home/kbulgrien/tmp/rpmpopt -> rpm/rpmpopt-4.4.2.3
```

Comment: @kulgrien That did not work actually,
cp -s libAbc.so src/
cp: `src/libAbc.so': can make relative symbolic links only in current directory

Comment: BTW, I agree with Maxim Egorushkin regarding use of `rsync`.

Comment: The answer no longer suggests `cp -s`.

Answer (score 2):

`rsync` is less error-prone then `cp`:

```
rsync -av libAgent.so* src/
```

Comment: Note that rsync is vulnerable to the same issue that the soft link in the new location is not guaranteed to work.  I.E. `rsync -av /usr/lib/rpmpopt ${HOME}/tmp` on my machine creates a broken link `rpmpopt -> rpm/rpmpopt-4.4.2.3` because my local copy has no *rpm* sub-folder.  One needs to consider this fact when deciding what to copy.

Comment: @kbulgrien This is true, but for a use case of copying a directory where symlinks point only within that directory, this works pretty well. Alternatively there are `--safe-links` and `--copy-unsafe-links` command line options.

Comment: Yes, it is true that `rsync -a` resolves the OP's use case, so forgive the nitpick, but I believe that `-L` aka `--safe-links` or `--copy-unsafe-links` makes a copy of the referenced file instead of a symbolic link.  (Kudo's for suggesting rsync, BTW).

Comment: @kbulgrien Well, versioned `.so` symlinks should stay symlinks.